# Aspose text replacement in PDF doesn't rearrange content

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose

I'm using Aspose to replace a set of words in an existing PDF file via a WPF application.

I took a look at this https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Replace+Text+in+a+PDF+Document
But the section 'Text Replacement should automatically re-arrange Page Contents' didn't help solve my problem which is exactly what is described in the section.

> "However recently some customers encountered issues during text
>   replace when particular TextFragment is replaced with smaller contents
>   and some extra spaces are displayed in resultant PDF or in case the
>   TextFragment is replaced with some longer string, then words overlap
>   existing page contents."

The problem is if I replace a word by a shorter or longer word, there's either a blank gap or overlap.

I tried some options such as

```
textFragmentAbsorber.TextReplaceOptions.ReplaceAdjustmentAction = 
TextReplaceOptions.ReplaceAdjustment.WholeWordsHyphenation;
```

or AdjustSpaceWidth
but is has no effect at all.

My code is the same as the one I linked above except I only replace the text and let the rest untouched.
Also my TextFragmentAbsorber looks like this

```
var textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber("(?i)("+ text.OriginalText +")", new TextSearchOptions(true));
```

With text.OriginalText being the text I want to replace with case insensitive regex.

Comment: Depending on how text is internally drawn in the source PDFs in question, faithful text replacement is or is not feasible. Your quoted paragraph down plays that a bit, probably because customers have been promised a sure faithful solution.

Comment: @niky,
The problem might be specific to structure of input PDF file which you are using. So please share the file for further investigation.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response but the goal here is to have any kind of file structure to go through the application, I just tested a few and saw the unexpected results. Another unexpected result is the text going out of readable bounds instead of continuing to the next line.